# How to clone values in vector<char**> to vector<char**>*? in c++

Tags: c++, mysql, pointers, vector

I´m making(re-making) a wrapper class to connect to mysql in a project, the thing is mysql connector returns the values from the select query in rows which are of type char**, so i thought of storing them in a vector<char**> as you can see in my code

```
#include <vector>
#include <mysql.h>
 
//query is a member function of wrapperclass
//conn is an already initialized MYSQL* object

void query(string str, vector<char**>* result = NULL)
    {
        if (!this->isReady()) throw std::exception("Not Connected");
        if (result)
        {
            const char* q = str.c_str();
            int qstate = mysql_query(conn, q);
            if (qstate == 0)
            {
                MYSQL_RES* res = mysql_store_result(conn);
                MYSQL_ROW row;
                vector<char**> temporaryResult;
                while (row = mysql_fetch_row(res))
                {
                    temporaryResult.push_back(row);
                }
                //Here i need to pass the values (not the pointers) from temporaryResult to result, 
                //which is a pointer to vector<char**> 
                mysql_free_result(res); //this function release the pointers stored in temporaryResult 
                                        //which is why i need to clone them
                mysql_refresh(conn, REFRESH_GRANT);
            }
            else
            {
                char buffer[100] = "";
                sprintf_s(buffer, "Connection DB query Exception: %d\n", qstate);
                throw std::exception(buffer);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            const char* q = str.c_str();
            int qstate = mysql_query(conn, q);
            if (qstate != 0)
            {
                char buffer[100] = "";
                sprintf_s(buffer, "Connection DB query Exception: %d\n", qstate);
                throw std::exception(buffer);
                mysql_refresh(conn, REFRESH_GRANT);
            }
        }
    }
```

i thought of making a function to clone each value 1 at a time but i don´t know how to find the lenght to of the char** to feed the "for" structures so i can´t do that either

Also i´m trying to avoid the need of passing the function the number of columns, or internally would be the lenght of the array of chars*

PD: i could change the args and return type of my function but i already started working in my project and it would be so much of a hussle to change everything, so if it´s not necessary please avoid that

Comment: First of all, one rarely need a pointer to a container (like `std::vector`). Use *references* if you need to pass a container as an argument.

Comment: Secondly, if you need an "array" of strings, use a `std::vector` of `std::string`. If you do then the "cloning" is as simple as an assignment!

Comment: I really think you should treat `MYSQL_ROW` as an opaque type. It could change at any time.

Comment: When i call the function i pass a reference to the vector, i only used a pointer here to be able to use the default null. But I´m realizing thanks to you that the pointer is to an already initialized vector, so thanks for that. Is it really that bad to use a pointer in this case?

Comment: Personally I would return a vector (of `std::string`).

Comment: you mean a vector of vectors of strings or a vector of strings array?

Comment: as far as  understand, now I'm returning a vector of char** which is like char[][]

Comment: Well it depends on what you're doing. More likely I would fill a `struct` that mirrors the fields of a row in the table.

Comment: I´ll take a look into the "opaque type" which is a completely new term for me. Thank you

Comment: If you are sure that the char** value returned is an array of strings then you could convert it directly to a std::vector<std::string>

Comment: Have you checked the [MySQL API doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-fetch-row.html)? You can get the length.